# what's the best method for transferring directory from remote host?

Tags: linux, networking, filesystems

I have a directory that's about 5G big. I'm about to run a series of tests but I want to know if I can exclude any tool or method from it:

We are going to

- a - tar the whole directory first

  1. tar cp | ssh
  2. tar cp | nc
  3. rsync -av -e ssh
  4. scp -c arcfour
- b - try to copy the directory directly

  1. tar cpz | ssh
  2. tar cpz | /nc
  3. rsync -avz -e ssh
  4. scp -c arcfour

Is there anything I can exclude, be it a) or b) completely, or any subset of a or b?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The preffered method to doing this job is rsync - you can retry if something went wrong.

```
$ rsync -avz /path/to/dir user@remote.tld:/path/to/dest
```

If you want to see progress add -P option

Comment: Assume this is a one time transfer by the way.

Comment: If this is a one-time thing, just any method is fine that meets your requirements. Why bother to try to find the hypothetical *optimal solution*?

Comment: Maybe RFC 1149 for a one-off transfer?

Comment: You are also unsing compression to transfer with -z option

Comment: Svan you are a troll, you have added nothing to this thread its obvious he could use the ultimate solution again the future.

Answer (score 1):

This is dependent on a lot of things, so there is no single *best solution*, IMHO, but I usually use just `rsync` on the directory anyway.

Things to consider:

- If the transfer is slow and the directory changes during transfer, rsync can update the target really easy.
- Copying multiple files is a bit slower than one big archive
- Transfer via SSH has a bit of overhead, but nc is unencrypted.